# How can i get device name Like: iphone pro max, Samsung galaxy S20 Ultra, etc

Tags: mobile, device, user-agent

I want to get the device and all info when user hit the url from the browser or app
How can i get the all details Like: iphone pro max, Samsung galaxy S20 Ultra, etc..

composer require jenssegers/agent.

Want to retrieve detailed device information when a user accesses my website or app, can i utilize the jenssegers/agent package in Laravel. This package helps you detect the user's device, browser, and other relevant information based on the user-agent string.

Give the solution.

Thank you.